# Hot to remove special chars from filenames and rename them in a directory?

Tags: bash, rename, regex

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

pushd DirectoryName

for file in *.csv; do
    #echo $file
    filename=${file%.*}
    file_clean=${filename//[ ()$+&\.\-\'\,]/_}
    final= "$file_clean.csv"
    mv "$file" $final
done

popd
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd DirectoryName
for file in *.csv; do
    filename=${file%.*}
    file_clean=`echo $filename | tr -cs "[:alnum:]_" _ `
    final="$file_clean.csv"
    echo "mv \"$file\" \"$final\" "
done
cd ..
```

The only changes are:

1) There was a space after the = in the line `final= "$file_clean.csv"`.  I have removed it.

2) Instead of using the string substitution command I have used the `tr` command. With tr, the `-c` option says to replace any character that is **not** in the set. So I can specify the characters I want to keep (alphanumerics and the underscore, in this case) and all the others will be transformed.

This should match some more special characters that are hard to specify via direct substitution, such as `[]\{}` and `"`.   The `-s` option means that only one underscore will be generated even if suppressing multiple characters. Thus `abc((((())))).csv` translates into `abc_.csv` instead of `abc__________.csv`

Comment: You can do the same as `2)` without using the external executable `tr`: `file_clean=${filename//[^[:alnum:]]/_}`. You can suppress the runs of multiple characters like this: `shopt -s extglob; file_clean=${filename//+([^[:alnum:]])/_}`

Comment: Cool. I didn't know you could use character classes in bash substitutions. Thanks.

Comment: I'd put a -n flag onto the mv command. If you happen to have two filenames which clean up to the same name then you'll overwrite & loose one.